# Beginning OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I have certain knowledge in Android and I would like to learn OpenCV,for this I have followed several tutorials and ended up doing the following steps.

```
  1. Download an eclipse for C/C++ developers
  2. Added the Android plugin
  3. Set the path for NDK
  4. Downloaded OpenCV Library and samples
  5. Imported the library and samples in the eclipse
  6. installed OpenCV manager in my device
```

But, to my dismay,a cross appears in the library folder and all other sample folders shows a foot-mark or build error, which step am I missing out. Please help. Thx in advance.

Comment: I have also done the steps below, but on running a sample app my device shows a black screen

Answer (score 2):

Right click on `project -> properties->android`. Add android library to your android project

Add opencv library into your project. Right click on `project -> properties->android` add library

To convert project into `c/c++ project`

Right click on `project -> New -> other -> c/c++ -> convert to c/c++ project`

If you have converted your project into `c/c++ project` ensure as follows

Right click on

`project -> properties->c/c++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> includes -> GNU c     and GNU c++ add the path E:/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include`

Similar to this

Also add the path `C:\OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include` as above

Comment: how to convert a project into c/c++ project?,also I cannot find C/C++ general under properties

Comment: When I added android.jar to OpenCV Library, the error mark got resolved from the library but an error mark came,just on the project name folder, to the project which I converted to C/C++ project.

Comment: what does problem description tab for your project in eclipse show?

Comment: One build error in the OpenCV library is C:\Program Files\Android\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8e\build::\ndk-build.cmd

Comment: Did you convert your openCv library into c/c++ ?Convert only your project which uses openCv library into c/c++ and its not neccessary to convert if you are using Cygwin to compile your NDK code.

Comment: How can I undo the convertion?

Comment: I dont know how to undo the convertion. But to compile NDK in eclipse Just Right click on project -> properties-> c/c++ build -> Builder Setting -> add ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd  in Build command: NDKROOT is path to your NDK.Try This.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29828/discussion-between-swetha-kini-and-sanghita)